# How to test require statement with hardhat?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm testing a smart contract that has a require statement in one of the functions.

In the past, I would just write.

```
await expect(token.transfer(user.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("10")).to.be.reverted;
```

But recently it stopped working, and it gives me this error:

```
Property 'reverted' does not exist on type 'Assertion'.ts(2339)
```

Any ideas why it's not working properly, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wondering if you found a solution to this?

Comment: @Will Yeah since I'm using typescript I didn't import chai properly. If you need I can add the code.

Comment: @Kuly14 please do so. If you find the answer to your own questions, it's always nice to provide the answer, for future peeps.

Comment: @MrFrenzoid good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I didn't import chai correctly.

So to solve this I created another file called `chai-setup.ts` and added this code inside:

```
import chaiModule from "chai";
import { chaiEthers } from "chai-ethers";
chaiModule.use(chaiEthers);
export = chaiModule;
```

Then in my main test file, I added this import statement:

```
import { expect } from "./chai-setup"
```

And that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to answer, but you can use [hardhat chai matchers](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-chai-matchers/docs/overview) to solve this issue.

Install hardhat chai matchers by

`yarn add --dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers`

Now all you need to is import it in your hardhat config by:

`import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers";`
or
`require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers")`

Now you will be able to use `reverted` and other stuff.